# Animating UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uipickerview

Hi I am developing an iPhone app which uses pickerview, Upon shaking app selects one random choice. Everything works well but I was wondering is there any way to animate the UIPIckerView as Urban Spoon has done it.

Answer (score 1):

Confession time: when I posted the other answer, I hadn't ever used Urban Spoon, and I assumed you were being lazy. I'm not overwriting my earlier answer, because such a rude response deserves the downvotes it got.

If I were going to make an animation like the ones on urban spoon's picker wheels, I'd probably use UIImageView's flipbook-style animation, as demonstrated here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/animated-gif-animated-images-iphone-style.html

Short version: the property `UIImageView.animationImages` can be loaded with an NSArray of UIImages. You can set properties like `.animationRepeatCount` and `.animationDuration`. And then `[UIImageView startAnimating]` will make that thing start animating.

I'd guess Urban Spoon does that for a second with the "fast rolling" set of images, replaces that with the "medium-speed rolling" set of images, and then gets rid of the UIImageView entirely and replaces it with a UIPickerView that's animating its way to a pre-selected random position.

Comment: I don't think that's what they are doing.

Comment: @Dan Ray Nice observation. I also think that Urban Spoon really used image views animation. Ones might notice the gap between two overlapping views; the image view does not completely cover the picker view. But upon finishing the selection, it shows a little bit animation of UIPickerView too.

Answer (score -1):

The method you want is

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

All else fails, you could always try looking at the docs. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Comment: I am already doing this, I need to animate it like urban spoon has done it.